# Scheduling wakelock on Android

Tags: java, android, cpu-usage, wakelock, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a foreground service running in my app and when a method in this service is called a ScheduledExecutorService is used to call another method in set intervals.

This method acquires a wake lock so it can run even if the device is locked.

It works, but I feel like that is not effective and battery consuming.

Which brings me to my question - is it possible to somehow schedule the wake of a CPU instead of holding the CPU awake all the time?

I tried releasing the wake lock at the end of this repeatedly called method, hoping that the ScheduledExecutorService will wake up the CPU when the next check occurs, but it does not.

Is it possible to do this? How else would apps like messenger or email notify you when you get a message?

Comment: Did you try to work with `AlarmManager`?

Comment: That does seems like a possibility, thanks! I'll take a look at it :)